# Help with this animation loop

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, svg

```
t.grow = function(parent,evt) { 
evt.target.Y = 0
var r = parent.radius, that = this
this.loop = function() {
    parent.root.suspendRedraw(10000)
    evt.target.Y = evt.target.Y - 6
    evt.target.setAttribute('transform', 
              'translate(' + 0 + ',' + evt.target.Y + ')')
    r = r + 0.1
    evt.target.setAttribute('r',r)
    parent.root.unsuspendRedrawAll()
     if(evt.target.Y < parent.timeout) {
        clearInterval(that.timer)
     }
}
that.timer = window.setInterval(this.loop,30) 
}
this.el.addEventListener("mouseover",
function(event){ 
    t.grow(parent,event)
},
true)
```

I really need some help with the above animation.

At the moment the animation is triggered on a mouseover of the object, but what I would really like to achieve is rather than the animation being triggered on an event I would like it to fire at a random time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function start(){
  grow()//You will need to pass in whatever element you want this to act on.
  setTimeout(function(){start()},(Math.floor(Math.random()*10)+5)*1000);
}
```

Basically the second line creates a random number between 0 and 10 then it adds 5 so that you won't have two animations running back to back.